# Secured SSO enablement for two app using different authentication method

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I currently have a requirement for this usecase.

I embed an app (App B) inside an app (App A).
My requirement is once I logged in to App A (via SSO), when I navigate to embedded App B screen, I can be redirected immediately into a page in App B without logging in again in App B.

I'm having issue with this because currently both App A and App B using different authenticate method to Active Directory, that's why the session created after App A login cannot be read when login activity in App B happening. Attached is the illustration for the authentication method
[Authentication Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFer0.jpg)

The reason is App A in the internet, while App B is within firewall and I don't want to publish it to internet. Currently App A method is using ADFS, while App B method is using LDAP.

Trying to connecting App B using ADFS but it didn't work

Any alternative solution to solve the requirement?

Thanks